# How to decrypt a folder using crypto in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, directory

I have read all the topic about decrypting a text file but nowhere I am finding how to decrypt a folder after encryption. I need a way out to decrypt my folder. my part of making encrypted file given

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', key);
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc',key)
var input = fs.createReadStream('content.zip');
var output = fs.createWriteStream('output.enc');
input.pipe(cipher).pipe(output);

output.on('finish', function() {
  console.log('Encrypted file written to disk!');
});
```

Comment: are you sure you read everything?... have a look in here http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/

Comment: @Habibul I'm not sure, I understand what your issue is. You're talking about encrypting and decrypting a folder, but a ZIP file is not a folder. It's a file that can contain folders and other files. Then you show some code, but you never describe what the issue is with this code. Please [edit] your question to make it clear what you mean and what the errors are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decrypt a stream you need to pipe the cypher to the decrypter

This will encrypt a stream, decrypt it and write it to file

```
input.pipe(cipher).pipe(decipher).pipe(output)
```

though this process seems redundant you can probably find something to fit you needs

Comment: ending up by generating a 0kb file on output. this is not working

Comment: is the encryption process successful?

Comment: @HabibulHasan I just double checked myself and the process I gave you works as expected, so maybe share more info about your process. Do you receive any errors? can you perform parts off the process - encryption/decryption alone?

Comment: the encryption process was successful, there was no error.i am trying it again

Comment: and the output of the encryption is greater than 0kb?